# Prove that A = B ⇒ A⋂B = A⋃B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This one's a simple one, just asking for confirmation...

Here's my proof :

```
Since A=B, then A⋃B = A⋃A = A                             ...1
and for the same reason : A⋂B = A⋂A = A                   ...2

So, from 1 and 2, we get : A⋂B = A⋃B
So, A = B ⇒ A⋂B = A⋃B
```

The reason I'm asking for confirmation for this is because my textbook  had a longer method for doing this and this method just seems too small compared to that one.

Let me know if this is right

Thanks

Comment: Your proof is correct.

There are several methods to proof this. Maybe your textbook tries to make the general method clear, to show the equality of sets, which is most of the time done by showing the two implications "$\subseteq$" and "$\supseteq$".

Comment: Yeah, got it, thanks :)